# JAVA Inserting into multiple tables with multiple rows depending on earlier ID

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, insert, dao

I'm trying to create something where i can insert a workout into the database with the excercises done in that workout. The problem is i want to create them at the same time and to store the excercises i use a link tabel.

This table is named Workout_Excercise so i can store multiple excercises each workout.

The problem is want to be able to create those at the same time, but the workout_excercise needs the workout_id that is yet to be created.

My current code inserts the workout which works just fine, now im curious how i would be able to insert the excersises aswell.

Current code for inserting workout:

Front

```
        $(".insertWorkout").on("click", function(){
            if(localStorage.getItem('token') != null ) {
                var token = localStorage.getItem('token');
             }
             else {
                 var token = null;
             }
        $.ajax({
             url: '/project/restservices/workouts/insert',
             type: 'POST',
             beforeSend:  function(xhr){
                 xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
             },
             data: {
                 titel: $(".workoutTitel").val() ,
                 beschrijving: $(".workoutBeschrijving").val(),
                 categorie_id: $(".categorieSelect").val(),
                 persoon_id: 1
             },
             success: function(response) {
                 if(response){
                     $(".workoutTitel").val("");
                     $(".workoutBeschrijving").val("");
                     $(".messageSpanSucces").html("Oefening invoeren gelukt");
                 }
                 else {
                     $(".messageSpanFail").html("Oefening invoeren mislukt");
                 }
             }
         });
    });
```

WorkoutResource

```
    @Path("insert")
@POST
@Produces("application/json")
@RolesAllowed("user")
public Response saveWorkout(@FormParam("titel") String titel, @FormParam("beschrijving") String beschrijving,
        @FormParam("categorie_id") int categorie_id, @FormParam("persoon_id") int persoon_id) throws SQLException {
    WorkoutService service = ServiceProvider.getWorkoutService();
    boolean country = service.saveWorkout(titel, beschrijving, categorie_id, persoon_id);

    return Response.ok(country).build();
}
```

workoutService

```
    public boolean saveWorkout(String titel, String beschrijving, int categorie_id, int persoon_id) throws SQLException {
    return WorkoutPostgresDao.saveWorkout(titel, beschrijving, categorie_id, persoon_id);
}
```

The workout DAO

```
    public boolean saveWorkout(String titel, String beschrijving, int categorie_id, int persoon_id) throws SQLException {
    boolean result = false;
    try (Connection con = super.getConnection()) {
        String query = "INSERT INTO \"Workout\" VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
        pstmt.setString(1, titel);
        pstmt.setString(2, beschrijving);
        pstmt.setInt(3, persoon_id);
        pstmt.setInt(4, categorie_id);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        result = true;

    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Don't you have an entity for workout?

Comment: Is workout_id primary key ??

Comment: i do have a entity for workout! this contains title and description and stuff. but that table is a link table so the workout can have multiple excercises. also yes workout_id is primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below approach to fetch generated keys :

```
try (Connection con = super.getConnection()) {
        String query = "INSERT INTO \"Workout\" VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
        String query2 = "INSERT INTO Workout_exercise ... ";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query,PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        pstmt.setString(1, titel);
        pstmt.setString(2, beschrijving);
        pstmt.setInt(3, persoon_id);
        pstmt.setInt(4, categorie_id);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        result = true;

        try (ResultSet rs = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys()) {
                    if (rs != null && rs.next()) {
                        workout_pkey = rs.getInt(1);
                        PreparedStatement pstmt2=con.prepareStatement(query2);
                        ...

                        for (Workout_exercise ex: exs) {
                              pstmt2.setInt(1, workout_pkey);
                              ...

                              pstmt2.addBatch();
                        }
                         pstmt2.executeBatch();

           }
       }    
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This looks interesting but what if i want to insert multiple excersises at once?

Comment: I see, so could i send a javascript array with all excersises to then batch insert? Thanks alot btw